# How to remove the background color for the regionfunction option in contourplot3D?

Tags: plotting, regions

Suppose that I want to plot only *a part of* a given surface using ContourPlot3D, such as the upper hemisphere of a sphere. I could do this using the *RegionFunction* option as follows:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},  RegionFunction -> (#3 > 0 &)]
```

However, this results automatically in a blueish grey shaded background in the region specified by RegionFunction, i.e. it yields the figure below. Is there a way to remove this color? The documentation of RegionFunction is not very extensive and I do not find any options to specify the color.

[image]

Comment: RegionBoundaryStyle -> None

Comment: @cvgmt That works, thanks!